# delete an object in an array based on index at level 1 and level 2

Tags: javascript

I have a array of object which has sub arrays, I want to delete the subarray object based on the index from both the levels.

For example if want to delete object with id:12 I should pass firstIndex = 0 and secondIndex = 1;
Pls note above mentioned eg: is for better understanding of question and not to delete element by id should be deleted based on index only(use case is different and index are received from different source).

```
const array = [
    {
        id: 1,
        row: [
            {id: 11, value: x},
            {id: 12, value: y},
            {id: 13, value: z},
        ],
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        row: [
            {id: 21, value: a},
            {id: 22, value: b},
            {id: 23, value: c},
        ],
    }
]

firstIndex = 1, secondIndex = 2

const result = [
    {
        id: 1,
        row: [
            {id: 11, value: x},
            {id: 12, value: y},
            {id: 13, value: z},
        ],
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        row: [
            {id: 21, value: a},
            {id: 22, value: b},
        ],
    }
]

firstIndex = 0, secondIndex = 1

const result = [
    {
        id: 1,
        row: [
            {id: 11, value: x},
            {id: 13, value: z},
        ],
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        row: [
            {id: 21, value: a},
            {id: 22, value: b},
            {id: 23, value: c},
        ],
    }
]
```

`const result = array.map((el, i) => (i === firstIndex) && el.rows.map(elm, (elm, index) => (index === secondIndex ) && elm.splice(index, 1)`))

Comment: And what exactly is the question now?
Could u clarify the ouput you want?
Just delete by index is no difficulty coz u just splice it out?
What exactly is the input u give and the output you want

Comment: `array[firstIndex].row = (array[firstIndex].row.splice(secondIndex,1),array[firstIndex].row)` in general should do but you have to test cases like `firstIndex` existing etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove Item from array by splice method like this:

```js
const array = [
    {
        id: 1,
        row: [
            {id: 11, value: 'x'},
            {id: 12, value: 'y'},
            {id: 13, value: 'z'},
        ],
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        row: [
            {id: 21, value: 'a'},
            {id: 22, value: 'b'},
            {id: 23, value: 'c'},
        ],
    }
]

firstIndex = 1, secondIndex = 2;
array[firstIndex].row.splice(secondIndex, 1);
console.log(array)
```

Comment: Why `globalThis.firstIndex` ?

Comment: _should be deleted based on index only_

Answer (score 0):

By adding the optional chaining: `?` you assure that the code works even if your indexes are wrong, it then just doesn't change anything and you won't get an error

```js
const array = [
    { id: 1, row: [{ id: 11, value: "x" }, { id: 12, value: "y" }, { id: 13, value: "z" }, ], },
    { id: 2, row: [{ id: 21, value: "a" }, { id: 22, value: "b" }, { id: 23, value: "c" }, ], }
]

function deleteByIndex(array, index1, index2) {
    array[index1]?.row?.splice(index2, 1)
    return array
}

console.log(deleteByIndex(array, 1, 2))
```